# Mobile phone field in form

Tags: javascript, html

I want to build mobile phone field in my form like the image given below.
[image: mobile phone field]

brackets has three digits next portion also has 3 digits and last section has 4 digits.How can I achive this.

Comment: Asim's question is perfectly fine, why the down votes?

Comment: Thanks Greg for your answer and inquiry.

Answer (score 3):

To do this yourself, you will need to pre-populate the field with the pattern as in the picture above, and react to the `keypress` event, adjusting accordingly.

If the character at the current position is "_", allow a number to be entered, otherwise move the cursor forward one position.

Here's a quick and dirty example below. Obviously more care will need to be taken to handle deleting characters and clicking into the existing telephone number, but as an example this should get you going.

```js
magicInput.value = magicInput.placeholder;
magicInput.addEventListener("keypress", key);
magicInput.addEventListener("focus", focus);
magicInput.addEventListener("mouseup", focus);
magicInput.addEventListener("input", focus);

function key(e) {
  if(!e.key.match(/\d/) || this.value.length > this.placeholder.length) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}

function focus(e) {
  let i = 0;
  
  for(i = 0; i < this.value.length; i++) {
    if(this.value[i] === "_") {
      break;
    }
  }
  
  this.setSelectionRange(i, i + 1);
}
```

```css
input {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<input id="magicInput" type="text" name="mobile" placeholder="(___) - ___ - ____" autofocus />
```

Comment: Thanks,Can we restrict last section to input only four digits,right now we can enter many digits.